# Predicting Rank of Google Result

Tags: regression, classification, ranking

I am trying to predict when one website will beat out another on google. I have three variables for each website, a Page Authority (P), a Domain Authority (D), and a Keyword Relevancy (K).

What I am trying to model is essentially when is f(P1,D1,K1) > f(P2,D2,K2).

I currently have a bunch of keywords and the top 10 webpages with their P,D, and K. However, I can't seem to find a good model to find f. I was trying to do some linear regression, however I don't know how to model **linear regression** as greater than something else. Only when it has a definitive result.

The other option I was considering was a **classifier**, but every keyword has such a different level of competition that it isn't that pages of certain p,d,k will be ranked #1. On a obscure keyword (ex. Jebediah the Ostrich) you could rank #1 without much of a web presence while on others it requires you to be well known (ex. Statistics)

And an **ordinal logistic regression** seems to be down the right path, but I just want to know what will beat another not an ordering of all 10.

What model do you use to find if one set of values is predicted to be greater than another?

Comment: This is too simple to be an answer, but "Learning to Rank" is the keyword usually used in machine learning, and there's a rich literature on it. Ordinal Logistic Regression is problematic because the rank isn't an absolute level.  What's usually used is a classifier on the differences of the X variables:

so that you maximize $1/(1+exp(-((P1-P2) + (D1-D2) + (K1-K2)+\alpha))$ in a logistic regression.